# Gerar número de consulta?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Tenho um sistemas de busca e quero gerar um número para cada buscas feitas no banco de dados, estou pensando em usar o `rand` para gerar os números, depois pegar o número gerado e salvar no banco de dados.

Seria uma boa ideia usar função `rand` para isso?

Exemplo:

```
include_once('conexao.php');

$nome = $_GET('nome');

$n = rand(0, 100000);

$cons = "INSERT INTO nconsulta (n1consultan, nome) VALUES '$n', 'nome'";
$executar = mysqli_query($conexao, $cons);
```

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor o que seria o "número para cada consulta" e descrever o por quê necessita disso e como será utilizado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Alguma necessidade específica para o número aleatório? Uma id com auto incremento não seria melhor? Pois, por menor que seja a chance, certamente uma hora o rand vai dar um número repetido. Pra não correr esse risco, você primeiro iria precisar consultar se o Rand não existe no banco e aí sim gravar.

Answer (score 5):

Você marcou essa pergunta com as tags [php](/questions/tagged/php) e [banco-de-dados](/questions/tagged/banco-de-dados). Apesar de não ter usado a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), vejo no seu exemplo de código que está chamando `mysqli`, então pressuponho que esteja usando alguma versão do MySQL. Se estiver errado, por gentileza, nos diga.

Não foi fornecido informações o suficiente para  "adivinhar" como você está rastreando essas buscas. Ou qual a sua intenção com elas. Se você deseja rastrear cada busca individualmente (por exemplo, gerar um log cronológico) sugiro que grave isso em uma tabela dedicada e use uma chave primária `id` com o tipo `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Talvez também seja interessante um ou dois campos que armazenem o *timestamp* da consulta, para que você possa ter rastreabilidade cronológica e não apenas numérica.

Manter uma coluna `id` do tipo `AUTO_INCREMENT` em chave primária é um coringa para resolver a maior parte das lógicas relacionais que você pode ter. Te permite buscar os mais antigos, mais recentes, ordenar, agrupar ou filtrar com facilidade. Se tiver os campos de data como auxiliares, maior granularidade ainda.

```
CREATE TABLE query_log (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     query_string TEXT NOT NULL,
     created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
     updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL
   );

INSERT INTO query_log (query_string, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES("frango frito", NOW(), NOW());
```

Se você deseja, no entanto, armazenar consultas **únicas** ao seu sistema de busca (ex: quer saber que pesquisaram "frango frito", mas não quer uma entrada para cada consulta) você ainda pode usar o mesmo campo `id` com `AUTO_INCREMENT` conforme mencionei, apenas verifique se o texto da consulta já existe antes de salvar.

Usando o seu "exemplo":

```
include_once('conexao.php');

$nome = $_GET('nome');      // Isso aqui deveria ser a "frase" da consulta???
// $n = rand(0, 100000);    // Não precisamos mais "gerar" o ID

$cons = "INSERT INTO query_log (query_string, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('$nome', '2018-11-07 11:21:00', '2018-11-07 11:21:00')";
$executar = mysqli_query($conexao, $cons);
```

Como você gostaria de lidar com datas (no caso de lidar com datas), fica a seu critério. Pode escrever manualmente as funções que melhor lhe servem ou se quiser uma biblioteca que forneça esse tipo de auxílio pode experimentar o [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

A verdade é que, sem informações mais específicas, qualquer resposta será especulativa e sua precisão será tão subjetiva quanto a própria questão. Existem inúmeras maneiras de implementar o que você escreveu, o certo ou errado depende daquilo que você quer; que é exatamente o que não está claro.

Você poderia gerar um *hash* da consulta, criptografar os resultados e fazer um `XOR` depois inverter os bits e mandar pra um servidor assinar pra verificar a autenticidade e depois retornar para o seu backend. Precisa fazer isso? Muito provavelmente **não**. Mas só você pode nos dizer.

Sinceramente acredito que, neste caso, usar literais de datas ou funções de UID são overkill, desnecessárias ou vão trazer outros problemas no futuro.

A propósito, tratando-se de PHP, um dos problemas do código PHP demonstrado acima é a facilidade de uma pessoa má intencionada de injetar código em seu banco de dados e causar todo tipo de problemas. Existem funções nativas para preparar sua consulta e na medida do possível evitar uma injeção de código malicioso através do seu sistema.

Sugiro que leia na [documentação oficial do PHP sobre o MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) antes de prosseguir com o seu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pegar a hora atual e multiplicar com algum valor aleatório, ou até mesmo o último id do seu banco.

```
    $id=10;
    $data = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
    $x = $id*strtotime($data);
```

Comment: Isso vai estourar a capacidade de armazenamento numérico fácil fácil.

Comment: Verdade, mas a ideia era evitar múltiplos acesso no mesmo tempo. Poderia somar com o id então.

Comment: Daria pra fazer algo misto, tipo pegar o strtotime * 1000 + ( id % 1000 ), mas ai teria que ajustar pro caso dele (esse 1000 seria supondo que não vai ter 1000 inserçoes no mesmo segundo, mas teria que garantir isso) - uma coisa que ajudaria seria ele "encurtar" o strtotime() tirando uns 40 anos (valeria de 2010 pra frente só) - mas no futuro precisaria revisar pra não estourar inteiro (em 64 bits nao teria problema)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que se você puder explicar melhor sua necessidade do número randômico alguém possa te mostrar um caminho melhor.

A princípio, se não há nenhum motivo para esse número ser aleatório, o MySQL conta com o campo "auto-incrementável", que vai gerar um número diferente para cada linha. ([Veja mais aqui.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html))

Caso isso não supra sua necessidade, você pode desenvolver uma lógica para gerar um ID randômico, baseado na hora atual entre outras coisas. Algo como isso aqui:

```
$uid = hexdec(uniqid());
// exemplo de saída: 1616475946956388
```

Lembrando que o `uniqid` retorna números em sua representação hexadecimal, por isso é necessário sua conversão para ter apenas números, como no código acima.

Você também pode acrescentar a data atual (unix) para torná-lo ainda mais único:

```
$uid = time() . '' . hexdec(uniqid());
// exemplo de saída: 15415914151616475760156156
```

Assim você não precisará fazer uma consulta no banco antes de inserir uma linha para verificar se o ID já existe.

Comment: Se é pra usar numérico não tem porque usar uniqid, melhor pegar o tempo puro (que é de onde o uniqid tira o hexadecimal, afinal de contas). Porém, só o tempo, pode dar um problema de race condition caso ocorram 2 inserções no mesmo segundo

Comment: Exatamente. Por isso acho mais interessante usar os dois, para diminuir consideravelmente os riscos de conflito. Apesar do uniqid utilizar o tempo, a saída não é a mesma.